# Remove from middle of navigator stack

Tags: flutter

Is it possible to remove a route from middle of navigator stack?

```
RouteA -> RouteB -> RouteC -> RouteD -> RouteE
```

To remove `RouteE` we call `.pop` , Is it possible to remove `RouteC` without removing `RouteD` and `RouteE` ?

I just want to remove `RouteC` from navigation stack, We don't remove other routes, If the user pressed back button twice , we will pop `RouteE` then `RouteD` and now we are in `RouteB` not `RouteC`

Comment: there is no such way if you have to use `pop` - however it is possible to skip it using other `pop*` methods

Comment: Can you explain more? I don't have to use `pop`

Comment: so use `popUntil` for example

Comment: `popUntil` will remove `RouteD` and `RouteE` too

Comment: i dont get it, so you want to pop to `RouteB` still keeping routes `D` and `E`?

Comment: No, I just want to remove `RouteC` from navigation stack, We don't remove other routes, If the user pressed back button twice , we will pop  `RouteE` then `RouteD` and now we are in `RouteB` not `RouteC`

Comment: then your real goal is to skip route `C` when pressing the back button from route `D`? in other words: you pressed back on `E`, now you are on `D` and by pressing back again you want to be on `B` route, right? if so use `WillPopScope` in page `D` where you can intercept back button and use `popUntil` method

Comment: alternatively use `MaterialApp.router` and the new `Navigator` v2 features, more: https://medium.com/flutter/learning-flutters-new-navigation-and-routing-system-7c9068155ade

Comment: I cannot use `WillPopScope` because I don't  know which route is after `RouteC` the use can go to may router from `RouteC`

Comment: you dont have to know if they all use `WillPopScope`

Comment: **if they all use WillPopScope** ? OMG! it's too many routes!

Comment: or even better, instead of using `WillPopScope` use a custom `MaterialPageRoute` and override `Future<RoutePopDisposition> willPop() async {` method

Comment: indeed: custom `MaterialPageRoute` is much easier: i implemented `MyMaterialPageRoute.willPop` method in simple 5 lines of code and it works just fine